# Dynamic style inside SVG

Tags: javascript, css, svg, transform

The code below seems to work in FF but not Chrome or Phonegap. What I hoped was that dynamically changing the class would effect both the regular div and the text in the svg. Firefox does that correctly, but Chrome only changes the svg text's font family and not the transform. Phonegap doesn't touch the svg text at all.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>

function getStyleSheet(unique_title) {
  for(var i=0; i<document.styleSheets.length; i++) {
    var sheet = document.styleSheets[i];
    if(sheet.title == unique_title) {
      return sheet;
    }
  }
}

function change() {
  var ss = getStyleSheet('dysty');
  ss.deleteRule(0);
  ss.insertRule('.narr { font-family:Courier; transform:scale(1,2); -webkit-transform:scale(1,2);}',0);
}
</script>

<style title='dysty'>
.narr { font-family:Arial; transform:scale(6,1); -webkit-transform:scale(6,1); }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<h2 onClick='change();'>change</h2>
<center><div class='narr'>Blah</div></center>
<svg id="pic" height='50' viewBox='-100 -25 200 50'>
  <text text-anchor='middle' id='t' class='narr' >Foo</text>
</svg> 

</body>
</html>
```

Anybody got a better idea? I have a lot of texts in this svg so manipulating them individually seems unattractive. OTOH I've yet to prove that this way is any faster.

All I really wanted was a way to zoom the svg (by messing with the viewBox) such that the font sizes stay the same. I'm not preserving aspect ratio in that zoom so my text looks really silly if I can't protect the font from that viewBox zoom or cancel it out with another transform.

TIA, Adrian.

Comment: Why are you rewriting the stylesheet?  Is there a reason you are not doing the more obvious things, such as appending a new class name that over-rides the old class? Or alternatively just directly updating the element style?

Comment: I have lots of elements conforming to just a few classes, so it seems more efficient to only change the class. Also, I'd like to do as much updating as possible in response to touchmoves, so they have to be very fast.